# fruit ninja Blade effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, particles

i want to make fruit ninja blade. i am using cocos2d and the MotionStreak is really ugly for this. Any other approach or better settings for MotionStreak? maybe particle system? any free great tools similar to ParticleDesigner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have my own implementation with OpenGL triangle strips mapped with texture. The blade is very smooth if the distances between adjacent points are small enough. I use linear interpolation to insert more points between two points which the distance is greater than a predefined constant. I'm thinking of use order 2 interpolation but the implementation is more difficult and the performance may reduces.
Source code is available here https://github.com/hiepnd/CCBlade

Comment: hey, you are so cool. could you give me more details on how to use it? does it support ipad?

Comment: I've just added a sample project to the repository and update README. CCBlade works on iPad too

Comment: it will crash when tapping instead of slicing. and when i use it in my project, it always says the #import <list> does not exist.

Comment: I downloaded your source code and ran the example project. Great work you've done there.
But I couldn't understand the readme provided if it is to be used someplace else. You've said to change the file type? But the description isn't clear. Can you please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: @Xohaib: CCBlade.m uses some C functions so it must have the file type as sourcecode.cpp.objcpp (Objective-C++ source in Xcode 4). You may also have to change the file type of files that use CCBlade.

Comment: I have Download project but i have developed my project in objective C with ARC,and i want to use Slice effect in my Project..can you suggest any tutorial or demo project to fulfill my requirement ?! @hiepnd

Comment: I have a similar requirement as the last poster - any advise on how I can get this project working  with ARC using iOS 6.1 (I have XCode 4.6) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how much effort it will take but the thing is you can create and change shape of filter and just apply a white to gray gradient as it's texture, it'll give a very good looking results. i myself am working with cocos2d-x (it's just a c++ port of cocos2d) and it has samples for dynamic filters (it's just like you create and manipulate a mesh and all the things are done automaticaly), it uses CCActionGrid class but i just didn't used this class yet if you couln't solve your problem using that ask me to search deeper.

Comment: how about the settings for motion streak? CCMotionStreak* streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:0.7f minSeg:10 image:@"gradient.png" width:32 length:32 color:ccc4(255, 0, 255, 255)];    it still looks like separated images connected one by one. i need them to be a single line.

Comment: please also check my another question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368690/fruit-ninja-blade-effect

Answer (score -2):

http://pixlatedstudios.com/2012/02/fruit-ninja-like-blade-effect/

Worth Checking out!!!! based on hiepnd CCBlade tutorial.